# How I can allow google request in my web page

Tags: php, laravel, google-search

I am allowing some specific pages on my web page. How can I allow google request to fetch my page information

```
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
<h1 itemprop="name">Shiny Trinket</h1>
<img itemprop="image" src="{image-url}" />
<p itemprop="description">Shiny trinkets are shiny.</p>
</body>
```

This is my page. But I am allowing only those persons to see my page who is login.

When I want to share from google it render my page and due to login permission its request move to login page.

How can I allow google request to fetch my page without login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I read somewhere that it is possible to pass login and password to google index bot. Try `Google WEBMASTERING`

I am not sure?!

> https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/85892/allowing-googlebot-to-crawl-a-password-protected-page

Comment: How you do in your case?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
@can('your_role')
<h1 itemprop="name">Shiny Trinket</h1>
<img itemprop="image" src="{image-url}" />
<p itemprop="description">Shiny trinkets are shiny.</p>
@endcan
```